# draw CGImageRef (not UIImage) into image context

Tags: cgimageref, uigraphicscontext, drawinrect

Here's exactly how to draw a UIImage in to context:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
[someUIImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(...)];
[someOtherUIImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(...)];
[someOtherUIImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(...)];
UIImage *yourResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

No problem.  However, say I have a CGImageRef which was built up somehow.

```
CGImageRef happyImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(blah blah);
```

I want to draw it in to the context.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
[ happyImageRef .. somehowDrawInRect:CGRectMake(...)];
UIImage *yourResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

How do you do that?

To be clear, obviously you can just **convert it to a UIImage**

```
UIImage *wasteful = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:happyImageRef];
```

But that seems incredibly inefficient. How to do it?

I'm sure I'm confused or missing something simple, so thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [CGContextDrawImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawImage)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(...), happyImageRef);
UIImage *yourResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Magnificent - that's it. You're the best. Thanks so much. (I just realised it's **reversed** left-right, of course!)

Comment: You're still the best and it's still magnificent!